# Detecting a collision between two colliders

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm developing a game in unity using UnityScript. I've initially created two objects, a sphere and a cube, having respective colliders. Now I'm trying to detect a collision between them using the below UnityScript function. But I'm not able to detect collision. I've also added a rigid body component to both of them. How can I detect a collision?

```
function OnCollisionEnter(col : Collision)
{
    if(col.collider.tag=="Cube")
    {   
        Debug.Log("collision");
    }
```

Comment: this is not enough code

Comment: Please add input and output data. Give comments where you think your problem is and what you intend to do. We need enough information to understand and reproduce your issue.

Comment: My javascript file contains this much of code with header '#pragam strict' and I added it to sphere object.

Comment: Are you missing a closing brace for your function? Is this script on the sphere? Does the cube have the "Cube" tag?

Comment: Unity wouldn't be able to compile and thus you couldn't test in the editor. I'm assuming that's a c/p error.

Answer (score 2):

Things to verify:

1. Make sure the script(s) are attached to the game objects
2. **UPDATED:** Make sure the class you have this code in inherits from MonoBehaviour (C#, boo)
3. Make sure collider components are attached to the game objects and that "Is Trigger" isn't checked as OnCollisionEnter won't be fired if it is.
4. Make sure the gameobject has the "Cube" tag assigned in the inspector

Also, the rigidbody component only adds physics to the objects and is not necessary when simply detecting collisions.

Comment: I agree all of them except 2. Because Nirmal uses javascript (unityscript).
Using Javascript every script automatically derives from MonoBehaviour. When using C# or Boo you have to explicitly derive from MonoBehaviour.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @BarışÇırıka.

Comment: I verified all your possibilities except 2. Still my code isn't working

Comment: Did you add rigidbody?

Comment: [Notes: Collision events are only sent if one of the colliders also has a non-kinematic rigidbody attached. Collision events will be sent to disabled MonoBehaviours, to allow enabling Behaviours in response to collisions.](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html)